# problems with calculating byte offset

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, adobe, offset, postscript

I'm tring to understand PDF struckture right now but I have a little Problem with calculating the byte offset of an String. The offsets of the objects are couted fom the begining of the file to the index of the object (**6** 0 obj).

I have a working hello world PDF file but when I count the offsets I get a diffrent offset than in the xref table.

**If anybody understands how this is counted please let me know!**

Example:

**0 6 obj** xref:9 me:17

**0 1 obj** xref:60 me:72

**0 4 obj** xref:145 me 187

(I count with "\r\n" (2) as line break)

Adobe Standart:http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/PDFReference.pdf

```
%PDF-1.4
%%EOF
6 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 5 0 R
>>
endobj
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 5 0 R
/MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ]
/Resources 3 0 R
/Contents 2 0 R
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/Name /F1
/BaseFont/Helvetica
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Length 53
>>
stream
BT
/F1 24 Tf
1 0 0 1 260 600 Tm
(Hello World)Tj
ET
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Kids [ 1 0 R ]
/Count 1
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/ProcSet[/PDF/Text]
/Font <</F1 4 0 R >>
>>
endobj
xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f
0000000060 00000 n
0000000228 00000 n
0000000424 00000 n
0000000145 00000 n
0000000333 00000 n
0000000009 00000 n
trailer
<<
/Size 7
/Root 6 0 R
>>
startxref
488
%%EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very interesting file and reading the PDF specification initially just confused me more :-). In such cases (I'll madden some people with this) I would simply save the example PDF file and do as @KenS suggests in his previous answer; open it in Acrobat and if Acrobat reports it as damaged or asks you to save when you close the file - it doesn't like it and you can assume you've gotten it wrong.

The reason this file is interesting is the second line, the:

```
%%EOF
```

I don't agree with KenS that having this line automatically invalidates the file - I can find no text in ISO 32000 that states this. The text says that the %%EOF line *at the end* of a file has syntactical meaning (and explains why it is there) and it states that any line beginning with a percentage character (%) is *a comment* and what that means. But nowhere does it state that %%EOF is not allowed as comment somewhere else in the file (though I consider it a dumb thing to do but that is something different).

If that %%EOF line isn't there, the XREF table is correct. If it is there, its wrong. Some more explanation of what I read in the documentation:

1) As far as I understand the offset is starting from the first byte of the file (it's a byte offset, not a character offset) which is "0" and then counts up. The idea behind this is that you can open a file, set the file read position to a given offset and start reading. So if you open up the file in a binary editor that shows real bytes, the offset should match what you're seeing there. If your %%EOF line isn't there, that means the first object (6 0 obj) effectively begins at offset 9 (if you line ending character here is a single byte line ending). At this point it matches what is given as an example in the PDF specification itself, so I'm confident that offset of 9 is correct provided that second line (%%EOF) would not be in the PDF file.

2) That second line starts with a percentage sign which makes it a comment. The PDF specification states that a comment (everything from the % sign up to but not including the line end character) shall be interpreted as a single whitespace character. That's interesting and could lead to all kinds of speculation on what that means for the offset of the object following it but frankly all of that speculation is out of order and irrelevant because of what I stated before.

> The idea behind this is that you can open a file, set the file read position to a given offset and start reading.

That's exactly what the cross-reference table is for and it should be taken literally. In other words, assuming single-byte line ending characters, object 6 in your example file starts at offset 15 and that's the number that should be in the XREF table for that object.

Again, take @KenS' comment into account, you cannot just assume the line ending is two bytes, you have to know what they are (and they could be *mixed* so you can't even assume all lines have the same). If this file would have two byte line endings for all lines, your count of 17 would be the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assume a line end is a \r\n pair, it could be \r, \n or \r\n, you need to use a binary editor to be certain. We also cannot tell you which value is correct without access to the original file, a cut/paste as above simply isn't good enough, sorry. Though 9 cannot be correct *unless* that %%EOF is spurious......

Your quoted PDF file isn't correct anyway, you should not have %%EOF as the second line, that 'ought' to be a binary sequence of bytes with the high bit set to make sure PDF files are transferred as binary files.

How do you know the xref in your PDF file is correct ? If you open it with Acrobat does it offer to save changes on exit ? That's a sure sign that Acrobat rebuilt the xref for you, because it was incorrect.....

[edited for clarity and because too long for comments]

I should be clearer in my explanation. I contracted 2 statements into 1 in my initial answer, and intended to clarify it in the comments. The file is incorrect, the xref offsets appear to me to be wrong, and on initial inspection appear to be wrong by the %%EOF (but see later), which looks like it is bogus in some way (inserted by cut/paste, or by an editor, or something).

Technically you can have any text which begins % anywhere in a PDF file (but outside string and stream), provided you account for it properly and don't break PDF syntax. But I still would not put two %%EOF comments in a PDF file, its too likely to confuse simple minded PDF consumers.

I don't think that  having a comment before the `'x y obj'` statement is necessarily wrong (I wouldn't do it, but that's not the same thing). It also doesn't totally invalidate David's point about:

```
The idea behind this is that you can open a file, set the file read position to a given offset and start reading.
```

Provided that the PDF consumer is prepared to read a comment and doesn't expect whitespace or a `'x y obj'` statement (and I *have* seen PDF files which have preceding whitespace here). That is debatable, and while I would read the spec to say that the xref offset *ought* to point precisely to the first byte of the `'x y obj'` line, it doesn't actually say that in so many words in the spec. And a PDF consumer does need to be able to deal with comments during the course of the object definition itself. For example I think that this:

```
1 0 obj
%% Here's a comment
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 5 0 R
/MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ]
/Resources 3 0 R
/Contents 2 0 R
>>
```

Would be legal. The line begins with a '%', its not in a string or stream context, and doesn't break PDF syntax, the consumer should simply skip right over it.

This isn't **very** much different from:

```
%% Here's a comment
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 5 0 R
/MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ]
/Resources 3 0 R
/Contents 2 0 R
>>
```

Again, I wouldn't do that myself (or if I did I would point the xref to the start of the 1 0 obj, but I think its arguable that way.

But in the original example my binary editor says that (with 2 byte line endings) object 4 starts at offset 187, if I use 1 byte endings that comes down to 170. In order to get object one's xref to be correct I assume that the line endings are 1 byte, and I remove the "%%EOF\n". But subtracting 6 bytes from 170 still comes out at 164, so nowhere near the 145 the xref contains. I cannot see any way to get object 4 to be at location 145 without removing real PDF operators/structure.

Comment: *PDF file isn't correct* - the reasons you give are making the file look suspicious but not yet incorrect.

Comment: The last line of the PDF file is supposed to be a %%EOF, there really shouldn't be 2. Though (as usual) Acrobat tolerates this sort of thing. <continued>

Comment: The file is definitely incorrect though. The xref says object 6 0 is at offset 9, which is the beginning of the %%EOF, not the '6 0 obj' line. I suppose you could argue that, since comments are ignored, that is legal but its rather hair splitting. The spec says the xref offset should point to 'the beginning of the object'. That is one way to have the xref be correct though, and it would not surprise me at all if Acrobat ignored such a fine distinction. But there's no way to get the 1 0 obj at anything less than 64 bytes (even counting 1 byte line breaks), and the xref says 60.

Comment: I think if you remove the %%EOF from the 2nd line, and count 1 byte line breaks the xref works out correctly for objects 6 and 1, so that second line looks plain wrong. THe offset for object 4 looks all wrong though

Comment: As stated in my answer, I don't really agree with your statement about the fact that this %%EOF invalidates the file; I can't find any strong language making that case. But I do agree with the rest of your points and the calculation you make in here.

Comment: I was trying to explain that that wasn't the way I intended it to be read. The file is incorrect for reasons other than the presence of two %%EOF (the xref can't be correct), but initially the presence of the %%EOF looked like it was causing the byte offsets to be incorrect (in fact it can't be that simple, as later analysis of object 4 showed, but it looked that way for objects 1 and 6). The 'should not have' would have been better as a different sentence, at the very least.